# Questions re barcode scanning for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, zxing

2 questions about the open-source, zxing barcode scanner.

A) Can I customise the design of the scan overlay/viewport on the iOS? Ie: change the square/overlay/cancel button etc.
If so, how, or is there documentation?

B) Can zxing scan 1D product barcodes on iOS yet? I can't seem to find documentation on this? Otherwise what are my options for scanning both QR codes and barcodes with the iOS?

Thank you.

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make the source code do whatever you want, as it's open source. You can certainly customize what it looks like.

Yes, most of the 1D scanning code has been ported to C++ in this project. You can enable and use it.